# Using asserts in Ruby production... yes or no?

Tags: ruby, software-design

So, here's the deal. I'm currently working in a Ruby on Rails environment and have been for ~1 year now. Before that I was in C++/Java land for almost a decade. I'm (still) trying to figure out what the Ruby way is when it comes to asserts.

I'm not worried about the technical detail. I know TestUnit has asserts which can be used in the testing environment and I know I can add my own assert methods to my Ruby project and use them in production Rails to lock down known conditions. The question is: What is the Ruby way for ensuring something in code that I know should/not happen?

For the record, I've been asserting in tests and raising in production. I still can't help but miss my production asserts...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asserts really shouldn't be used in production code for two reasons.

1. `assert x` is very functional, and as such hard to read. Using a raise/if combo adds readability.
2. assert doesn't make it clear what error will be raised if the condition fails. While,

   `raise ObscureButInformitiveError if condition`

   lets the application layers further up do something relveant. Such as emailing an admin, or writing to a perticular log.

Comment: Throwing exceptions is okay so long as you have some kind of `rescue_from` handler installed that presents a nice error message for the user and you have something like `hoptoad_notifier` to trap and report on the errors for diagnostic purposes.

Comment: It's been a while now and I think this recommendation along with a service like [Airbrake](http://airbrakeapp.com/pages/home) is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Let the error happen, then check the logs for what went wrong, then fix it.
Rails catches all uncaught exceptions automatically, it will only mess up the single request the error happened in.

Comment: With nil values it is not immediately obvious when that value was set to nil. You have an exception trace but it only traces after the nil access happened. Consider a case in which a variable is passed through 5 methods, each of which can under certain conditions set the value to nil. The log isn't going to contain the full state information, so you probably will not be able to independently reproduce the error from the log + stacktrace. How do you reduce this complexity without asserts (or some assert-like functionality like unless a; raise Error)?

Answer (score 0):

There's no official non-test assertions in Ruby, but there are gems.

For instance Jim Weirich's [Given](https://github.com/jimweirich/rspec-given#non-spec-assertions) looks promising. Although its main focus is testing environments (rspec / minitest), but it also:

> ... provides three assertions meant to be used in
>   non-test/non-spec code. For example, here is a square root function
>   decked out with pre and post-condition assertions.
>
> ```
> require 'given/assertions' 
> require 'given/fuzzy_number'
>
> include Given::Assertions 
> include Given::Fuzzy
>
> def sqrt(n)   
>   Precondition { n >= 0 }   
>   result = Math.sqrt(n)
>   Postcondition { result ** 2 == about(n) }   
>   result 
> end
> ```
>
> To use the
>   non-testing assertions, you need to require the `'given/assertions'`
>   file and then include the `Given::Assertions` module into what ever
>   class is using the `Precondition` / `Postcondition` / `Assert` methods. The code
>   block for these assertions should always be a regular Ruby true/false
>   value (the should and expect methods from RSpec are not available).
>
> Note that this example also uses the fuzzy number matching, but that
>   is not required for the assertions themselves.